# What algorithm does networkx use in its shortest_path() function?

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path

Pretty much exactly what it says in the title. For example, I know there's also the option to use Djikstra algorithm for weighted graphs. But nowhere in the documentation does networkx specify the algorithm used for shortest_path(). Unless of course the algorithm is just shortest_path, in which case I'd feel dumb :)

Comment: http://networkx.lanl.gov/_modules/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/generic.html

Answer (score 2):

According to the *[source code](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/generic.html#shortest_path)* it uses BFS for all the shortest paths from a single-node in an un-weighted graph, and dijkstra for a weighted graph.